# Error al guardar fichero en ruta diferente a la raiz proyecto C#

Tags: c#, restsharp

Tengo una aplicación en C# que descarga ciertos ficheros de una API usando RestSharp, no tengo problemas cuando los descarga en la raiz del proyecto, pero si por ejemplo trato de que los descargue en la ruta C:/NombreProyecto/fichero.txt tengo un error de este tipo:

```
Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' en 
mscorlib.dll
No se puede encontrar una parte de la ruta de acceso 'C:\Directorio\name.txt'.
```

Cuando le indico que guarde de esta forma me da error:

```
client.DownloadData(request).SaveAs(@"C:/Directorio/"+id+"-name" + ".txt");
```

Pero cuando lo dejo sin ruta, guarda bien en el directorio raiz:

```
client.DownloadData(request).SaveAs(id + "-name" + ".txt");
```

¿De que forma debería indicarle que guarde en C o Mis Documentos?

Comment: Casi con total seguridad es un problema de permisos. Tu aplicación no tiene permiso para guardar en la ruta que le estás indicando. Para descartarlo, trata de ejecutar tu aplicación como administrador.

Comment: La aplicación apenas esta en desarrollo, como podria ejecutar como administrador? intente ejecutar los .exe en la carpeta debug  como administrador pero no me reconocen restsharp como libreria externa.

Comment: Entiendo que el directorio donde quieres copiarlo ya existe no? no? :)

Comment: No existe el directorio, intente cambiarlo a una ruta menos sencible que la de la raiz de C de esta forma: string pathMA = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
                Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments), "Logs", "fichero.csv"); pero sigue sin funcionar, en el debug veo que la ruta es correcta pero el no puede crearla y guardar.

Comment: Si no existe...como quieres que lo encuentre? Debes crearlo antes!!! Utiliza [CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Muchas gracias, aun no he usado CreateDirectory pero probé creando el directorio manualmente y ahora si funciono, puede ponerla como comentario para darla como solucion.

Comment: Ok,me alegro. Te he añadido una respuesta para que veas como gestionarlo con CreateDirectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras tus comentarios, el problema es simplemente que el directorio no existía. `SaveAs` espera una ruta que ya exista, en ningún caso va a crearla.

Puedes crearla tú haciendo algo como lo siguiente:

```
string carpeta =@"C:\Directorio"; 
if(!System.IO.Directory.Exists(carpeta))          //Si no existe ya la carpeta
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(carpeta); //la creamos
```